# SBT: how to override the default sources (and/or resources etc)?

Tags: configuration, sbt, subproject

I've been reading and re-reading the docs, and everywhere it just says that *by default* sbt uses the project base directory and src/main/scala to look for scala sources, but I could not find any mention of how that default can be changed.

I have seen vague references to an "exclude" filters, but what I need is the opposite.

I would like to compile a subset of a large scala project into a smaller self-contained artifact. Is there a way to tell sbt exactly what files I want it to include? Something like "**/util/*.scala"  for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to customize sources path in SBT:

```
scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src"
scalaSource in Test := baseDirectory.value / "test-src"
```

More in [documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html).